# Iterating over a concatenated array alters the items in the original arrays. Why?

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, concatenation

I encountered some unexpected behavior with Ruby arrays:

```
array1 = ["a"]
array2 = ["b"]
array3 =  array1 + array2

puts "array1 before array3.map!: #{array1}"
puts "array2 before array3.map!: #{array2}"
puts "array3 before array3.map!: #{array3}"

array3.map! { |item| item << "_modified" }

puts "array1  after array3.map!: #{array1}"
puts "array2  after array3.map!: #{array2}"
puts "array3  after array3.map!: #{array3}"
```

The terminal outputs:

```
array1 before array3.map!: ["a"]
array2 before array3.map!: ["b"]
array3 before array3.map!: ["a", "b"]
array1  after array3.map!: ["a_modified"]                #Unexpected
array2  after array3.map!: ["b_modified"]                #Unexpected
array3  after array3.map!: ["a_modified", "b_modified"]  #Expected
```

First Question: Why are the items in array1 and array2 different despite only iterating over array3? Concatenating two arrays returns a new array, so why are there lingering effects to array1 and array2?

Second Question: How can I change the items in array3 by iteration without changing the items array1 or array2?

Third Question: When .map and .each are used in place of .map!, the output is identical. So it would seem that .each and .map are changing the items in the array. Why does this occur?

Comment: After defining the three arrays, I obtained:  `array1.map(&:object_id)
 #=> [70229175091960]; array2.map(&:object_id)
 #=> [70229175065880];  array3.map(&:object_id)
 #=> [70229175091960, 70229175065880]`. Does that help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`array1` and `array2` are not modified. Strings `"a"` and `"b"` are modified.

Look at it this way:

```
string = "a"
array = [string, string, string] # ["a", "a", "a"]
string << "b"
array # ["ab", "ab", "ab"]
```

The array did not change. It is still `[string, string, string]`. But `string` is different.

**EDIT** To clarify, and repeat from comments, you did not modify the array. This is modifying the array:

```
array3.each_index { |index| array3[index] = item + "_modified" }
```

as you replace each element with another one. When you execute this, `array1` and `array2` print unchanged - their elements are kicked out of `array3` and replaced by something else. What you did:

```
array3.map! { |item| item << "_modified" }
```

appended `"_modifier"` to each item (without messing with its identity), then `map!` replaced each element in `array3` *with that same element*. Thus, `array3` still had the same elements as `array1` and `array2`, and any change in one was reflected in the other.

Comment: I thought that modifying an item in array is precisely what it means to modify an array.

Comment: OK, say you have a doll house with 3 dolls. You dip one of the dolls in blue paint. Is the doll house modified? It still has the same three dolls it had before. Sure, it looks different (just like `array1` looks different when you print it out), but it has the same contents it had before.

Comment: Let array = [1,2,3]. If array.map! { |val| i * 2 } , then it said that the array has been modified since now, the array is [2,4,6].

Comment: Welp, now you are in a very different territory, because numbers are immutable, whereas strings are mutable. "modify an array" means add, remove or replace an element, and `item << "_modified"` did none of those. Your array still contains the same elements, but those elements themselves are different.

Comment: Though this doesn't solve any of the problems does it?

Comment: Which problems? You had three questions, all of which built on the mistaken presupposition that `array1` and `array2` changed, and all of them being "why". There is no further problem to be solved in your question...? (unless "how not to share the reference" is your real question, in which case I think my edit might show you a way)

Comment: I just saw your comment edit. Indeed, `array.map! { |val| i * 2 }` will modify the array: `i * 2` creates a new number `4` that is distinct from `2` (as opposed to the impossibility of modifying `2` to be a `4`), and then replaces the array element with the new value. In your case, the key issue is that you replace the element with the *same* object (which you do a drive-by mutilation on), so the array stays the same. Be sure to see the difference between `x<<y` (modify `x` by appending `y` and return `x`) and `x+y` (concatenate `x` and `y` returning a new string).

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I see what you did there :) `enum = array3.each` would have been a better choice, as `map!` is messing up your arrays since you're not controlling the return value. (Actually have no clue how that happened, or what `map!` was getting...)

Comment: ...So that post wasn't a ghost after all.

Comment: Part of the problem is that I ran it multiple times without resetting the arrays to their initial values :-). My deleted answer now shows the results when the arrays are reinitialized. (Only members in possession of the magic dust--Amadan being one--can see that.) I'll have another look in the morning. (Too tired now.)